# Geometric distribution expected number of rolls

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A pair of dice are repeatedly rolled until the two sum to ≥10. The expected number of times the pair is rolled is?

I understand how to apply the geometric to get the probability of an event, but I do not understand how to use it to get the expected number of rolls (in this case) to achieve a certain result.

Comment: Can your compute the probability that the sum of two dice is greater than 9?

Comment: Probability that the sum of two dice id greater than 9.  1/6.  Unfortunately I still do not see how that lets me calculate the number of rolls to get a 10 or more with two six sided dice.

Comment: The expected value of rolls is simply $1/p $.

Comment: E(X) = 1/p.  First calculate p.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

First, the probability that two dice sum up to $\ge 10$ is $\frac16$ since there are six possible events, $\{46, 55, 56, 64, 65, 66\}$. Thus, if $X$ counts the number of rolls, then $\Pr(X = k) = \frac16$. You can now simply use the fact that $\mathbb{E}(X) = \frac1p$ and get 6. Alternatively, here is the calculation:

$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty k \cdot \Pr(X = k) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty k (\frac56)^{k-1}\frac16 = \frac16 \sum_{k = 0}^\infty k(\frac56)^{k-1}$$

Let $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$. Then for $x \in (0,1)$, we have $f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty x^k$. Thus, $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty kx^{k-1} = f'(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$. Therefore, $\mathbb{E}(X) = \frac16f'(\frac56) = \frac16 \frac{1}{(\frac16)^2} = 6.$